# How to boost relevance for exact match results when using wildcard in sphinx?

Tags: php, sphinx

This is my search request:

```
    (new SphinxSearch())
        ->search((new SphinxClient())->escapeString($query) . '*', 'services')
        ->setMatchMode(SphinxClient::SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED)
        ->setFieldWeights([
            'name' => 10,
            'legal_name' => 10,
            'description' => 10,
            'keywords' => 10,
            'category_name' => 3,
            'categories' => 3,
        ])
        ->setSortMode(SphinxClient::SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@weight DESC")
        ->setRankingMode(SphinxClient::SPH_RANK_SPH04)
        ->get(true);
```

And here is index config:

```
index services
{
    source = services
    path = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/services
    docinfo = extern
    morphology = stem_enru
    min_stemming_len = 1
    min_word_len = 1
    min_infix_len = 1
    html_strip = 1
    index_exact_words = 1
    expand_keywords = 1
    mlock = 0
    charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, *, -, a..z, \
                        U+2C->U+2E, U+2E, U+0044, U+0046, U+0130, U+0401->U+0435, U+0451->U+0435, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F
}
```

For a query "**school №4**" it returns all relevant results, but with something like "**school №42**" at the top and the exact match of "**school №4**" is close to the bottom of the result set.
Well, it's not actually an *exact* match - in the service name there may be some other words and symbols. But it's closest to what user entered in the search field, so I believe it should be more relevant than results with a wild card.

How can I move "exact" match to the top of the set?

P.S. I'm using [this](https://github.com/sngrl/sphinxsearch) Laravel specific wrapper for SphinxClient, though I don't think it's important.

Answer (score 0):

One option could, try the `expand_keywords` option
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-expand-keywords

> can possibly improve the search quality, as the documents with exact form matches should be ranked generally higher than documents with stemmed or infix matches.

Alas it's a index level config, rather than query. Can then remove the * from the query.

Comment: I have this option enabled. I've tried to remove wildcard, but only exact matches ("school 4" and no "school 42") were returned. Disabling this option has no visible effect on the result set.

Comment: Are you rebuilding the index when changing the option?

Answer (score 0):

Current solution that I have - make two queries with and without wildcard and then merge results with exact matches on the top. It works, but not ideal, obviously.